# Is the inverse of the metric tensor such that $g_{ij}g^{jk}=\delta_{i}^k$?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

The Minkowski metric tensor have the relation $\eta_{ij} \eta^{jk}=\delta_i {^k}$. That is the inverse of the Minkowski matrix is the matrix itself.
               Analogously, is it true that $g_{ij} g^{jk}=\delta_i {^k}$, where $g_{ij}$ is the metric tensor in a curved space? If yes how to prove this? I came up with the confusion  while finding the chrischoffel symbol I came up with a equation $$2 \Gamma^{\gamma}_{\alpha j} g_{i \gamma}=g_{ij,\alpha}+g_{\alpha i,j}-g_{j\alpha,i}  .$$ 
      To eliminate $g_{i\gamma}$ I have to find the inverse of the metric tensor in tensor notation. Can anyone suggest how would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix $(g^{-1})^{\mu\nu}$ of components of the inverse metric [tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field)$^1$ is *not* necessarily equal to the matrix $g_{\mu\nu}$ of components of the [metric tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor), if that's what you're asking.

However, there is a standard notational shorthand convention to write $(g^{-1})^{\mu\nu}$ as $g^{\mu\nu}$ because the upper indices already indicate that we're talking about the inverse metric.

--

$^1$ The metric tensor field is a covariant symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor field, while the inverse metric tensor field is a contravariant symmetric $(2,0)$ tensor field.

Comment: 1. $g^{j m}$ in the equation $\Gamma$:

$\Gamma^k_{li}=\frac{1}{2}g^{jm}(\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial q^l}+\frac{\partial g_{lj}}{\partial q^i}-\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial q^j})$ of Christoffel symbol is the component of the inverse of the matrix representing the metric tensor. Is it right? 2. But it is it a covariant metric tensor too?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No, it is instead contravariant.

Comment: What does (0, 2) tensor field and (2, 0) tensor field mean?

Comment: Hi @HelloGoodbye: Plainly speaking, it counts the number of upper and lower indices of the tensor components.

Comment: @Qmechanic Generally when looking at a tensor (field), how does one see if it is covariant or contravariant? Is the distinction important? For example, is the tensor $\Gamma$ in walber97's comment covariant or contravariant?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a metric tensor $g$ for which $(g^{-1})^{\mu\nu}\neq g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: E.g. $g_{\mu\nu}=2\eta_{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 3):

Even in flat spacetime, the metric does not have to have the form $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$. For example, if you want to do physics in SI units rather than natural relativistic units where $c=1$, then you want something like $g=\operatorname{diag}(c,-1,-1,-1)$. This is not the same as its own inverse.

Comment: And if you use anything else than Cartesian coordinates, the diagonal may look different, or the off-diagonal elements may even be non-zero if the grid axes are not orthogonal. I don't know why you would use such a coordinate system, especially in flat spacetime; I'm just saying that you can, and if you do it will cause the metric tensor to look different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this hasn't been mentioned before, but$$g_{ij}g^{jk}=g_{i\mu}g^{\mu k}-g_{i0}g^{0k}=\delta_i^k-g_{i0}g^{0k}.$$